# Firefox redirects the URL

Tags: firefox, redirection

Few months back, [kickass.to](http://www.kickass.to) changed to [kickass.so](http://www.kickass.so) and when I used to type kickass.to and enter, Firefox was redirecting me to kickass.so. Now kickass.to is back in action and kickass.so doesn't exist any more. Still, whenever I go to kickass.to, firefox redirects me to kickass.so. I deleted all the cookies, still the problem persists. Just to use kickass, I've to use chrome.

How to resolve this?

Firefox version: 33.1
OS: Fedora 21

Comment: Thanks. After clearing the browser cache, it's working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear the browser cache to resolve this issue.